# trying to get ICC color profile, but ColorContext ProfileURI is null

Tags: c#, image-processing

I am trying to get the ICC color profile information from an image file without using a third party library. ColorContexts is supposed to contain this information but I cannot extract the information, even if I save an image in PhotoShop with a specific color profile (e.g. Adobe RGB 1998, or US Swop V.2). I can see whether the image is CMYK or RBG, and the number of channels. But the Uri information is always null. What am I missing?

```
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
...
var frame = BitmapFrame.Create(imageStreamSource).ColorContexts[0].ProfileUri;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of this property can be null, however, you can get a `Stream` to the raw color profile using [OpenProfileStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Media.ColorContext(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: http://www.color.org/icc32.pdf describes the format of ICC profiles. System.Text.Encoding.UTF8